# How do you reply to an email expressing you agree?

Tags: выбор-слова, стилистика

I received the following email response to a request I had made:

> Здравствуй! Я тьютор тьюторской службы университета. Мы получили твою заявку
> на тьюториал, но, к сожалению, сейчас мы не проводим индивидуальные
> тьюториалы. Можем записать тебя на какой-нибудь день после 8 сентября?

It sounds quite friendly, yet formal/polite(*грамотно написано*). Please give me a possible reply to this email. I want to express that I'm ok with it, maintaining the style and tenor of this email.

I don't think

> Отлично! Жду дату

matches their style.

Comment: "Formal" and "grammatically correct" are different things, but this text is neither of them. Being on the _ты_ basis with a university student, using the word _тьютор_ in a Russian text and omitting _ли_ in the final question is not the style I would want to match. Your suggested response looks perfectly fine to me, is there any specific reason you don't like it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like your response - in the context of their very poorly written email.

The style they are using is completely *mauvais ton* for a university  on several points (so much so that I would hesitate to engage them), but I won't go into detail since that's not what your question is about. (Quassnoi mentioned most of the issues in his comment)

(This somewhat depends, however, on the request *you* sent prior to this — you mention this was a "response". They might be matching your style, but it's still unacceptable IMO. Also, I hope this isn't a machine translation of a communication in English - it does sound like one — that's how bad it is).

The reason I like your response is that it *does* match their (quite informal) style, yet avoids addressing them in the second person, where you'd have to choose ты (as they have) vs. вы (as it should be).

I would change it a bit, though. First, I would replace "отлично" with something like "это меня устраивает". This is because "отлично" is somewhat ambiguous: отлично what? That "сейчас мы не проводим" or "можем записать"?

Second, I would add "Жду *конкретную* (или *более точную*, etc.) дату".